Docker compose's /run/host-services for non-root users (ssh-agent sock)
I've managed to google this solution for using my local ssh key inside the container. It allows me to access git repositories and works ok.
services:
  app:
    ...
    environment:
      SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock
    volumes:
      - /run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock:/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock
    user: ${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID}

Recently I've switched images and now I'm not using a root user anymore, but despite the user option in the yaml config it's still owned by root.
/var/www/html $ ls -lA /var/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock
srw-rw----    1 root     root             0 May 15 11:47 /var/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock

I've tried googling about this magic host-services directory, but can't find any info (the sock file does not exist in that directory on my host machine). Right now I have to run docker exec -u root app_name sh -c "chmod o+rw /var/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock" after each image build/computer reboot and I would like to solve this issue but have no idea where to begin.
